# Aggregation with $gte and $lte in Parse-platform with parse-sdk-php not working

Tags: parse-platform

I'm trying to run a range query (`$gte`) and (`$lte`) using the aggregation of Parse-sdk-php and it's returning me empty

**Use case**

I have a collection of `referrers` that have the createdAt key, when searching using the parse `greaterThanOrEqualTo()`  and  `lessThanOrEqualTo()`  methods, it is returning results, however when `querying using the aggregation`, it returns an `empty array`.

**Pipeline**

```
$query = new ParseQuery('referrers);

// $dateStart is an DateTime object
// $dateEnd is an DateTime  objectThis text will be hidden

$pipeline = [
    'match' => [
     'referrer' => ['$exists' => true],
     'createdAt' => [
         '$gte' => ParseClient::_encode($dateEnd, true),
         '$lte' => ParseClient::_encode($dateStart, true)
    ]               
];

$query->aggregate($pipeline);
```

**Query String with decode url**

- Parse with methods `greaterThanOrEqualTo()`  and  `lessThanOrEqualTo()`

```
    {
       "referrer": {$exists: true}, 
       "createdAt":{
          "$gte": {__type: "Date", iso: "2020-01-01T17:15:40.000Z"},
          "$lte": {__type: "Date", iso: "2020-12-31T17:15:40.000Z"}
       }
    }
```

- Parse with the aggregation

```
    {
        "referrer": {$exists: true}, 
        "createdAt":{
            "$gte": {__type: "Date", iso: "2020-01-01T17:15:40.000Z"},
            "$lte": {__type: "Date", iso: "2020-12-31T17:15:40.000Z"}
        }
    }
```

Settings

```
    OS: WIN 10 20.04

    php -v:
    PHP 7.4.9

    parse php sdk version:
    "parse/php-sdk" : "1.6.*",
```

Comment: Could you please try with _created_at?

Comment: 'match' => [
    'referrer' => ['$exists' => true],
                  '_created_at' => [
       '$lte'  => ParseClient::_encode($dateEnd, true),
       '$gte'  => ParseClient::_encode($dateStart, true)
    ]
       ],



did not work

Comment: Just sent you another suggestion in the forum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```php
'match' => [
       'referrer' => [
              '$exists' => true
       ],
       'createdAt' => [
               '$lte' => ParseClient::_encode($dateEnd, true)['iso'],
               '$gte' => ParseClient::_encode($dateStart, true)['iso']
       ] 
]
```